# no user id for key signature packet of class 10

Tags: arch-linux

So, I was installing some packages with pacman (Arch Linux) and noticed this error (no user id for key signature packet of class 10). Everything went fine, but what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

In the output of

```
sudo pacman-key --list-keys
```

at the top I had the same message

```
gpg: key 786C63F330D7CB92: no user ID for key signature packet of class 10
```

I've installed GnuPG using `pacman`:

```
sudo pacman -S gnupg
```

Note that I'm just an ordinary user. After that the message dissapeared. Hope that helps you.